# Image fill entire container area that inherits height from other content (no set height)

Tags: html, css

I have a section with `min-height: 100vh`. The section in then split into 2 parts, the left part contains a list of links and the right part displays an image which has 100% height.

When hovering over these links the `src` of the image on the right will change to display an image associated with the link (there is also an image that is displayed by default).

What I am struggling with is how to make the images fill the whole right `<picture>` container **without expanding it in any way**? So the image will either be the min height of 100vh OR the same height as the list (if it's over 100vh) I feel like I should be using background-image or something and that this is quite basic, but I'm stumped!

Here's my structure in HTML with inline CSS:

```html
<section style="min-height: 110vh; display: flex">
  <article style="min-width: 50%; border-right: 2px solid black;">
    <ul style="padding: 48px; gap: 32px; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
      <a href="">One</a>
      <a href="">Two</a>
      <a href="">Three</a>
      <a href="">Four</a>
      <a href="">Five</a>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <picture style="flex-grow: 1; object-fit: cover; background-color: aquamarine">
    <img src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" alt="image" style="display: block">
  </picture>
</section>
```

Comment: For info - with my current structure, the container just stretches to the size of the image, both vertically and horizontally...

Comment: Could you include the code in a snippet so it's easier to play around with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your picture tag with

```
<div style="flex-grow:1; object-fit:cover; background:url(https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png) aquamarine no-repeat center center / contain;"></div>
```

Please let me know if this helps :)

Comment: You know what this was the shortest answer but was exactly what I was looking for.

Instead of the shorthand however, I chose:
    background-image: url('Images/Home/hapa.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center

Answer (score 2):

You could define the ***width*** in ***view port*** `vw` units. Also, move the `object-fit` ***property*** to the **image**.

[Gif showing dynamic properties](https://gyazo.com/40273fa3dffde776f90f8a171fab939c)

```css
/* margin and padding reset and box-sizing to border-box for all elements */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  width: 100vw; /* changed to view width so parent takes up all view port width */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* added to center items vertically in flex container */
}

.article {
  width: 50vw; /* added view width to article so it takes up half of view port size */
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.listParent {
  padding: 48px;
  gap: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; /* added for vertical alignment of flex items */
}

.pic {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  /* width not needed here */
}

.pic img {  
  /* display block not needed */
  object-fit: cover; /* moved this property under image element */
  width: 50vw; /* added view port size so image only takes up half of view port */
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <article class="article">
    <ul class="listParent">
      <a href="">One</a>
      <a href="">Two</a>
      <a href="">Three</a>
      <a href="">Four</a>
      <a href="">Five</a>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <picture class="pic">
    <img src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" alt="image">
  </picture>
</section>
```

Comment: So first off, I learnt a lot from this so thank you!

The issue is that I'm not sure that it's 100% what I'm looking for  - maybe you can see by the floating border but I want there to be a min-height of 100vh.

The solution with background-image works perfectly with minimal restructuring however, so I'm going to mark that as correct

Answer (score 1):

Solution from CSS grid.

```css
section{
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
}

article {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

picture {
  background-color: aquamarine
}

picture img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <picture>
    <img src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" alt="image" style="display: block">
  </picture>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure that this works - try resizing the page with your example and the fish overflows its container (as does the list)

Comment: Did you checked my code? It works perfectly in all devices. Also look at my CSS, I have used minimum css to get it to work.  And also look at your `<ul>` and my `<ul>` list in left column. You have wrong HTML there.